# simple way to set left text margin for ToolStripTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Left margin for text in ToolStripTextBox control is too small. How to increase it?
Overriding OnPaint function gives no results.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolStripTextBox1.Margin.Left = 10 ;
toolStripTextBox1.Margin.Right = 10 ;
```

Comment: If you refer to the margins outside the textbox border (i.e. between toolstrip items), it works on my system. For margins inside the textbox, between the border and the text, I don't have a direct solution.

Comment: Yes, I need the distance between left side and first letter.

Comment: @OlegLeonov:  You may insert 2 other ToolStripTextBox on each side of your ToolStripTextBox, with Width=10 & Enabled=False.  For all 3 ToolStripTextBox: BorderStyle=None, BackColor=Color.White and set all margins to 0.